# SHC Compiled script fails to run using systemctl

Tags: bash, systemctl

I've got a very simple bash script called test.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    currdate=$(date +%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S)
    echo -e "\n$currdate ..."
    sleep 1
done
```

Running this from the command line works exactly as expected.

I've compiled this with SHC has follows:
`shc -r -U -f test.sh -o test`

Running this from the command line works as expected.

I've setup to run this using systemctl, added my config file to `/etc/init.d` and this references `test`

If `test` is my un complied bash script, then `systemclt start test` works fine.
If I swap test and replace it with the complied version, then it fails.

systemctl status shows:

```
test.service - LSB: Test
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/test; generated; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-02-18 15:38:05 GMT; 6s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 18089 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/test start (code=exited, status=7)
    Tasks: 2
   CGroup: /system.slice/test.service
           ├─18096 /home/rocket/test -c                                                                                                                                                                                                  >
           └─18142 sleep 1

Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 systemd[1]: test.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=7
Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Test.
Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 systemd[1]: test.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 systemd[1]: test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

journalctl shows:

```
Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Test...
Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 test[18089]: Starting test
Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 test[18089]: 18/02/2020-15:38:05 ...
Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 test[18089]: ..failed
Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 systemd[1]: test.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=7
Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Test.
Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 systemd[1]: test.service: Unit entered failed state.
Feb 18 15:38:05 linux-c0a9 systemd[1]: test.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Does anyone know why this fails and how to stop it failing ?

I'm only using SHC to stop users editing the script, not for any security etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have solved this.

My script in /etc/init.d was calling `/home/rocket/test`

When that is a bash file it's fine, when it's compiled it stops working.

To get it to work I changed test to always be a bash file that calls the compiled test which is in in `/home/rocket/bin/test`